# Absolute positioning inside 100% width relative positioned div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I try to absolute positioning couple of `img` elements inside one `.branch_item` element who should have `position: relative`.

Everything works fine when `.branch_item` has `with` and `height` in `px`, but I need them in `%` not `px` (because this element should have 100% of `width`). The `%` unit works only with `fixed` position, but it can't be in that position.

My code looks like:

```
<div class="container left">
  <div class="twelve columns">
    <div class="branch_item">
      <div class="csc-row">
        <figure class="csc-image csc-image-first csc-image-last">
          <img src="uploads/pics/bg_01.png" alt="" />
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="csc-row">
        <figure class="csc-image csc-image-first csc-image-last">
          <img src="uploads/pics/de.act.png" alt="" />
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="csc-row">
        <figure class="csc-image csc-image-first csc-image-last">
          <img src="uploads/pics/lx.act.png" alt="" />
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="csc-row csc-row-last">
        <figure class="csc-image csc-image-first csc-image-last">
          <img src="uploads/pics/pl.act.png" alt="" />
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="twelve columns menu-bar">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is my css code:

```
.branch_item {
  background: #ECECED; 
  position: relative;
  top: 50px; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.branch_item img {
  position:absolute; 
  top:0px; 
  left:25%; 
  width:50%;
}
```

When I set in `.branch_item` element `width` and `height` in `%` unit I have blank page without anything.

Anyone know how to set it?

Comment: create jsFiddle, and expect some help.

Answer (score 0):

When you set width and height in percent, it takes the measurements relative to it's parent.
Do you have a set height and width on `<div class="twelve columns">`? (not in percentage)
If not, `.branch_item` cannot have percentage height.

Comment: I use the `foundation framework` and `.twelve` has { width: 100%; }

Comment: Yes exactly, so it has fluid height. So if you set .branch_item to have 100% height, that's 100% of what? The parent element doesn't have a height. It will therefore not show at all.

Comment: ok, I understand - the img element should expand this element, but how positioning images - they need to be absolute positioning, or not?

Comment: If you're just trying to nudge the images 25% from the left, why not just set margin-left:25%; on them? When you set position:absolute; on the images, it takes them out of the natural flow. The container needs them in the flow to give it height. Without the height, you've got nothing to position against.

Comment: not quite - the images should be in the same position - one above the other - thats why I use `position:absolute`

Comment: Why are you putting them all in different divs if you want them to appear in the same place?

Comment: they all form one whole, and using jquery i will disable some of them on hover event